# reportlab pdfmetrics ttfont postscript error

Tags: reportlab

I'm experiencing an error when I try to register a font through pdfmetrics. Is there something I do not take into account or is it the font that could be the problem?

**MY CODE**

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('{FONT_NAME}', str({FONT_PATH}.ttf'))
```

**ERROR TYPE:**

TTFError

**ERROR STRING:**

TTF file "{FONT_PATH}.ttf": postscript outlines are not supported

**ERROR FILE**

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py

**ERROR LINE**

228

---

in file /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py on line 228 the following error is raised:

```
if version==0x4F54544F:
    raise TTFError('%s file "%s": postscript outlines are not supported'%(self.fileKind,self.filename))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked after converting the same font (that works on my machine) from OTF to TTF through this converter https://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue in MPDF (PHP PDF conversion library), and tried the converter linked in the accepted answer above, but the converted file still generated the error.

I ran the conversion in [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/otf-to-ttf) and that worked.